# Unable to display queryset using ajax and Django

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates

I'm not able to display queryset while using ajax

here is my `views.py`:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    productid = request.GET.get('productId')
    print productid
    if request.is_ajax():
        try:
            queryset= StoreProduct.objects.get_size(productid)
        except:
            queryset= None

        data = {
            "queryset" : queryset
        }

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Here is my ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getStoreView(event, productId) {
        event.preventDefault();   
        var data = {
           productId : productId
        }
        $.ajax({        
            type: "GET",
            url: "{% url 'storeView'  user=store.user %}",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data.queryset)
            },

            error: function(response, error) {
                alert(error);  
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

What should I do to solve the problem above?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the output you get? Try printing just `data`.

Comment: Where exactly does it fail? Is the response returned correctly from the server? Do you jump into the success-callback?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you look at the error message from Django, you will see it complaining that the queryset is not JSON serializable. For ajax requests, you can see the response using your web browser's development tools when `DEBUG=True`.

The first thing to do is to use `values()`, which returns a queryset containing dictionaries for each instance in the queryset. Secondly, you need to coerce the queryset into a list.

```
queryset = StoreProduct.objects.get_size(productid)
values_list = list(queryset.values())
```

Comment: Don't worry about it, thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send queryset directory as json, because json is just a string. You could use django serializer to apply to your queryset:

```
from django.core import serializers

serialized_qs = serializers.serialize('json', queryset)
data = {"queryset" : serialized_qs}
return JsonResponse(data)
```

Also in your javascript you have to do `data['queryset']` to access your queryset as json.

Comment: Note that this will return `{"queryset": '<json_string_of_queryset>'}`. I think the OP probably wants `{"queryset": [<item1>, <item2>...]}`.

Comment: yeah i need {"queryset": [<item1>, <item2>...]}