# How do I send QuerySets with Django using AJAX?

Tags: django, ajax

So, I have submitted a form using AJAX to a Django application but I am finding it a bit difficult to send the output back to my site...

```
context = {
        "view":"trip",
        "listofTrips":zip(tripsData, tripsUserData),
        "noOfTrips":len(tripsData),
        "searched":True,
    }
```

So I have QuerySets as well as ZIP files to send, and I cannot save it anywhere as the zip file is a queryset and saving it then downloading it would reduce my performance greatly. For your information `tripsData` and `tripsUserData` are querysets.

The main reason I need it zipped is that in Django templates I have this piece of code `{% for trip, tripsUserData in listofTrips %}`. This allows me to use both variables in a single for loop.

So is there any method by which I can get that done without refreshing...We can't use a `JsonResponse` since I get a (500) server error...so how can I send my data?

Thanks!

Comment: Here ```zip``` is python's inbuilt function right ? Which zip file are you talking about ?

Comment: ```tripsData``` and ```tripsUserData``` are querysets ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358877/unable-to-display-queryset-using-ajax-and-django

Comment: Yes, @Prakhar I am sorry for the misunderstanding. Yes Zip is a python inbuilt function and `tripsData` and `tripsUserData` are querysets

Comment: @Akshay that is useful but i need to send it as a zip file...